# Understanding .gitignore

Tags: git

I have a .gitignore file in my root directory. The rule is to ignore all .txt files. In my root dir, I have two files namely, something.py and anything.txt.

I created the anything.txt file after writing the .gitignore.

So now, when I issue git add * ( after making changes in both the files ), it throws the following message: The following paths are ignored by your .gitignore file anything.txt. fatal: no files added.

But then, when I explicitly add something.py, it gets added..

So why isn't that .py getting added with git add *, even though its not mentioned in the .gitignore file?

Comment: Usually people use `git add .` instead of `git add *`, which doesn't produce such errors.

Answer (score 3):

When you type the command `git add *`, it is expanded by your shell to match all the non-hidden file in the current directory. In your case, it become `git add something.py anything.txt`.

Git thinks you want to add a file (`anything.txt`) matching the entry `*.txt` in your `.gitignore`. This is why it throws an error. The command has failed and no files were added.

To add all the files in the project, you mustn't rely on shell behavior (***** expansion). You should do it using `git add -A` or better, adding each logical pack of file individually.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how it works: `.gitignore` is simple mechanism to say git which file types should not be added to your repository.

For example, adding `*.txt` says you do not want to add text files.
But it does not say anything about python files, and they will be added as usual.

You can override `.gitignore` by using `git add -f file_or_dir`.
If you try `git add something.txt` while .txt is ignored, git will warn you and refuse to do that, unless you use `-f`.

Using `git add *` will try to add all files in current directory, including .txt, and this will cause warning. You can use `git add .` to avoid this.